# Azure iOS App authentication error

Tags: ios, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am testing out Azure cloud for mobile app and downloaded the sample app provided during the getting started section. I also configured Azure Active Directory to be used for authentication.

When I run the app on iOS simulator, I get an error in terminal saying:

> ERROR  Error Domain=com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorDomain
>   Code=-1302 "You must be logged in to use this application"
>   UserInfo={com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorResponseKey= { URL:
>   https://appname.azurewebsites.net/tables/TodoItem } { status code:
>   401, headers {
>       "Content-Length" = 45;
>       "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
>       Date = "Sat, 25 Jun 2016 10:46:04 GMT";
>       Etag = "W/\"2d-vonn2FgYR/Z6jU4A0udEWA\"";
>       Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.0";
>       "Set-Cookie" = "ARRAffinity=155c1827c98c621a5b3208e361587e118813cc4207f5ad4c23e121c5c10fd7bf;Path=/;Domain=appname.azurewebsites.net";
>       "X-Powered-By" = "Express, ASP.NET"; } }, NSLocalizedDescription=You must be logged in to use this application,
>   com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorRequestKey= { URL:
>   https://appname.azurewebsites.net/tables/TodoItem }} Error: Error
>   Domain=com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorDomain Code=-1173 "Push
>   aborted due to authentication error"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Push aborted due to authentication
>   error, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f84fb1bd910 {Error
>   Domain=com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorDomain Code=-1302 "You
>   must be logged in to use this application"
>   UserInfo={com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorResponseKey= { URL:
>   https://appname.azurewebsites.net/tables/TodoItem } { status code:
>   401, headers {
>       "Content-Length" = 45;
>       "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
>       Date = "Sat, 25 Jun 2016 10:46:04 GMT";
>       Etag = "W/\"2d-vonn2FgYR/Z6jU4A0udEWA\"";
>       Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.0";
>       "X-Powered-By" = "Express, ASP.NET"; } }, NSLocalizedDescription=You must be logged in to use this application,
>   com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorRequestKey= { URL:
>   https://appame.azurewebsites.net/tables/TodoItem }}}}

Nonetheless the app is working and I can save items and load data. How can I solve the below issue?

Comment: How did you configure the backend?  Did you set the Authentication / Authorization default action to be "Allow request"?  (This is required so that the app controls auth instead of the front end processors)

Answer (score 1):

The app probably appears to work because it is saving items to the local database, but you are getting errors when trying to sync. I'm guessing you configured authentication on a service level when you set it up. You can change it to only be required for particular endpoints by changing the setting in Authentication/Authorization under "action to take when request is not authenticated" to "allow request (no action)". See [How authorization works in App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-authentication-overview/#authorization).

For endpoints that do require authentication, you need to add code to login on the client. See [Add authentication to your iOS app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started-users/).